# can you allow only Ethernet packets destined to a certain MAC address through a network adapter?

Tags: windows-8, ethernet, mac-address, udp

I would like to transmit UDP ethernet packets from my PC to custom hardware (of known MAC address) which is directly connected with an ethernet cable using no switches.

Different services on the PC transmit packets/requests to the network adapter. I would like to limit these requests to only a specific MAC address or port.

Is it possible to specify which of these transactions are to be transmitted by the network adapter?

For further clarification i have added a picture of my adapter traffic. What I would like to do if block all transactions which are not 192.168.10 source, 192.168.1.11 destination. I am working on a windows system.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

UDP is a transport protocol which relies on IP. IP requires certain translations (ARP table) in order to send onto a network. If you want to use UDP, both sides need to understand protocols all the way up to UDP. UDP itself has no knowledge of any of the physical portion of the network (you can run UDP/IP or TCP/IP over other architectures, such as Infiniband, where there are no MAC addresses). The cards themselves do some filtering for MAC addressing as it is (your card will only accept broadcasts or packets specifically destined for your card - the switch has forwarding tables that also MAP out MAC to port in order to ensure packets go to the proper port).

Remeber - IPs and MAC addresses are not the same - if you want to limit by IP, as you suggest at the end of your question, then you can use some sort of IP firewall and just set rules to allow what IP traffic you want to allow in/out of your PC.